# how to create a dynamic query using 'IN' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I want to pass a string that contains many usernames, seperated by a comma,and want to pass it to query

```
   $name_list='kesong,nicholas,jane';   //this value would change
$select_occupy=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE `username` IN('$name_list') ORDER BY `occupy_date` ");// i think this would just search for a username which is 'kesong,nicholas,jane', instead searching them seperately
    echo mysql_num_rows($select_occupy); //would echo 0
```

I know it works only when you specify like IN('$name1','$name2','$name3'), but I need a dynamic one

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated

Comment: depends on the format and source of the original name list, array is easiest, you can just use implode

Comment: what do you mean?@Dagon

Comment: 1) *do not* use `mysql_*` 2) build an SQL string *with placeholders* 3) bind the placeholders to values (use `mysqli_*` or PDO) - there are *examples for this task* in the documentation

Comment: yes, as a beginner, I code almost entire website using mysql_, including select delete couples months ago, that's frustrated to change it into mysqli_,may be it's time for modification, thanks for suggestion@user2864740

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, just hold your names into an array and do like below:

```
$names=array('name1','name2','name3');
$namesToCheck="";
foreach($names as $name){
    $namesToCheck.="'$name',";
}
//to remove the last ,
$namesToCheck=substr($namesToCheck,0,-1);
```

Now, you can put `$namesToCheck` into your `IN` query.

**EDIT:**

In this answer, this is assumed that you will prevent any possible SQL injections as current answer is just an idea about your question. The minimum suggestion to perform preventing SQL injections would be using `mysql_real_escape_string` function, which escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement. For example:

```
$namesToCheck.="'".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."',";
//OR DO THIS ON FINAL STRING
```

**NOTE THAT This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0**. You can take a look at the PHP's official document in the following link:

[mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: I think this would check the username=$name1+','+$name2+','+$name3   instead check them username=name1||username=name2||username=name3

Comment: @user2864740 Modified ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
    $namesToCheck = "'" .implode( "','" ,explode( ',' ,$name_list ) ) ."'";
```

And then use the `$namesToCheck` in the `IN` clause of your query .

The above code would convert :

```
    kesong,nicholas,jane
```

to :

```
    'kesong','nicholas','jane'
```